# Using ctypes, how can I pass a Python 'bytes' value to a C function that expects an unsigned char pointer?

Tags: python, casting, ctypes, mypy

I have a C library with a function that has among others, a (const unsigned char *) type parameter, for which I want to write a ctypes-based Python binding.

In the Python version, I want to be able to pass a "bytes" value.

Passing the "bytes" value directly doesn't work. I get a ctypes.ArgumentError:

`ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 6: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ubyte instance instead of bytes`

I can get it to work, by casting the 'bytes' value to an unsigned char *, using the ctypes.cast() method. Which seems the obvious thing to do, works great, but then when I run mypy over my code I receive the following error:

```
source/pydwf/core/api/DigitalCanAPI.py:65: error: Argument 1 to "cast" has incompatible type "bytes"; expected "Union[_CData, _CArgObject, int]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 52 source files)
```

So, is there a way to write this that satisfies both Python (so it works) and mypy (so it is happy about the cast?)

Is this a bug in mypy perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can either construct a `c_ubyte` array directly, or cast it carefully through a `c_char_p()` instance to silence the `mypy` warning:

test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

// dump data as hexadecimal
API void func(unsigned char* data, size_t length) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        printf("%02x",data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.func.argtypes = POINTER(c_ubyte), c_size_t
dll.func.restype = None

# demo passing data that might not be nul-terminated
data = b'\x11\x22\x33\x00\x44\x55\x66'
dll.func(cast(c_char_p(data),POINTER(c_ubyte)), len(data))

bdata = (c_ubyte * len(data))(*data)
dll.func(bdata,len(data))
```

Output:

```
11223300445566
11223300445566
```

The script passes `mypy`:

```
C:\>mypy test.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: I like the double-case idea especially, but at least on my version of mypy (0.812, which is the latest one afaik) I still get warnings. What version are you using? Starts to look more and more like a mypy bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your cast is wrong because `char != unsigned char`. If you truly mean unsigned char, then you can't use all the char helper methods. You'll get weird errors on setups that define char to be signed. However, if you're happy that your implementation/c compiler will always define char as unsigned char then don't bother with `u_byte` at all. Just define the arg types and return types as c_char or c_char_p as needed.

If you need to stick with u_byte then this is correct and keeps mypy happ (without a cast).

```py
import ctypes.util

# or whatever to get some library function
libc_path = ctypes.util.find_library('msvcrt')
libc = ctypes.WinDLL(libc_path)

# snprintf actually takes char, but this should be fine for most setups
snprintf = libc._snprintf
snprintf.argtypes = (
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte),
    ctypes.c_size_t,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte),
    ctypes.c_int, # white lie about the number of arguments snprintf takes
)
snprintf.restype = ctypes.c_int


def to_ubytes(bytes_):
    # nul terminate the string just to be safe
    u_bytes = (ctypes.c_ubyte * (len(bytes_) + 1))()
    u_bytes[:-1] = bytes_
    u_bytes[-1] = 0
    return u_bytes

buffer = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 20)()
format_ = to_ubytes(b'hello %i\n')

result = snprintf(buffer, len(buffer), format_, 1234)

if result >= 0:
    result_bytes = bytes(buffer[:result])
    print('result is:', result_bytes)
else:
    print('snprintf encountered an error')
```